# Hibernate sum and group

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

everybody:

So, I have this system created with Hibernate and Spring, and I want to create Reports to see the total piece and the total sold per object, but I'm having troubles to understand how to create this Mysql query to hibernate criteria.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
 SUM(laborderdetail.total) AS suma,
 sum(laborderdetail.quantity) AS total,
 laborderdetail.`itemMaster_id` AS total,
 itemmaster.`ITEMNAME` AS total,
 udc.`STRVALUE1` AS total
FROM
 `laborderdetail` laborderdetail INNER JOIN `itemmaster` itemmaster ON laborderdetail.`itemMaster_id` = itemmaster.`id`
 INNER JOIN `udc` udc ON itemmaster.`linetype_id` = udc.`id`
 INNER JOIN `laborderdetail` laborderdetail_A ON itemmaster.`id` = laborderdetail_A.`itemMaster_id`
 INNER JOIN `laborder` laborder ON laborderdetail_A.`labOrder_id` = laborder.`id`
 INNER JOIN `laborder_laborderdetail` laborder_laborderdetail ON laborderdetail_A.`id` = laborder_laborderdetail.`labOrderDetail_id`
 AND laborder.`id` = laborder_laborderdetail.`LABORDER_id`
 AND laborderdetail.`id` = laborder_laborderdetail.`labOrderDetail_id`
 AND laborder.`id` = laborderdetail.`labOrder_id`
 AND udc.`id` = laborder.`rate_id`
 AND udc.`id` = laborder.`priceList_id`
 AND udc.`id` = laborder.`orderReference_id`
WHERE laborder.`company_id` = 1
GROUP BY
 laborderdetail.itemMaster_id
ORDER BY
 udc.STRVALUE1 ASC
```

I know I have to use criteria.setFetchMode to JOIN all my tables and then use ProjectionList for my SUM, but the way the system is programmed makes me confused cause in my model of LabOrder I have this code

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
private Set<LabOrderDetail> labOrderDetail;
```

So when I try this code:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(LabOrder.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("laborderdetail", FetchMode.JOIN);

    if (this.companyId != 0)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("company.id", this.companyId));
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("laborderdetail.itemMaster_id"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.sum("laborderdetail.total"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.sum("laborderdetail.quantity"));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("laborderdetail.itemMaster_id"));

    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

    List<LabOrder> list = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
```

I got this error with my line `projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("laborderdetail.itemMaster_id"));`

This is the error:

```
could not resolve property: laborderdetail.itemMaster_id of: com.gds.model.LabOrder
```

I know is cause itemMaster_id is in my model of laborderdetail, but how can I do my query?
Maybe it's silly thing but I don't have any clue since I'm not that familiarize with hibernate. 
Thanks.

Comment: itemMaster_id is the name of a column in the database or the name of a field in LabOrderDetail?

Comment: Yes, It's a column in the data base and I have a model (LabOrderDetail.java) with the same name  with the same name field.